# JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 1 in http://localhost:49870/Properties/\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error

Tags: javascript

I  am working With Dates in javascript here it is my code

```
var CurrentDate = new Date();
document.write("current date = " + CurrentDate); // Using new Date(), creates a new date object with the current date and time:
document.write("<br>")
document.write("<br>")


//Using new Date(date string), creates a new date object from the specified date and time:
var d = new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");
document.write("Specific date using overload constructor od Date(date string) = " + d);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");

/*Using new Date(7 numbers), creates a new date object with the specified date and time:

The 7 numbers specify the year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and millisecond, in that order: */

var a = new Date(99, 5, 24, 11, 33, 30, 0);
document.write("Specific date using overload constructor od Date(7 numbers) = " + a);
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");
```

I found similar type of question here but none of them are solving my problem ? any 1 have idea about it ?

Comment: I didn't get any error message.

Comment: when i debug my program it is throwing an error of the same title as i describe above :(

Comment: See this fiddle.. https://jsfiddle.net/nmq1jpm2/ I didn't get any errors.

Comment: i also run my script on different online compiler , but my VS is throwing an error . 
Note: only for this program , my other javascript program is running perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` returns the current time, not the current date.

Use :

```
new Date().format('m-d-Y h:i:s');
```

insted of **new Date();**

Comment: [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): _"If no arguments are provided, the constructor creates a JavaScript Date object for **the current date and time** according to system settings."_

Comment: If you want to declare Date object then extract the day,month,year seperately and them write them .

`var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear()
document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>")`